# Selenium message:unknown error: session deleted because of page crash

Tags: r, docker, rselenium, docker-selenium

I'm getting the following error when trying to run reselnium using docker in R.

Selenium message:unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from tab crashed

I changed chrome options based on the answers to some other posts but still not working.

```
chrome_options <- list(
  args = c("--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage","--disable-gpu", "--disable-software-rasterizer"),
  prefs = list("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" = 2)
)

remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAdd = "localhost",
  port = 4445L,
  browserName = "chrome",
  extraCapabilities = chrome_options
)
```